How to uninstall WSL from Windows 10
So basically I installed WSL from PowerShell using wsl --install command. After I didn't need use for it, I uninstalled Ubuntu from the apps and feature in settings. When I restarted my pc, the storage space is still occupied, and I cant find the culprit. Can someone please help me?

See my answers on the linked question for the correct steps.  I'll double-check my answers there later today to make sure they are still up-to-date.

If you have questions beyond that, please do let me know - You can @ reply to me here and we can look at editing the question to reopen it if needed.
